# Spring-boot stop application when internal error occurs

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have written the spring boot application . For my application configuration is mandatory which is loading the from the databases . If the application is started when the Databases is down, I want to stop the application by throwing exception .
How Do I stop the spring-boot application .

Comment: Stop tomcat.....